# Trying to understand the complete meaning of a below statement Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s$", "")

Tags: java, java-stream

I am adding screenshot for some more information. I am new to Java8, kindly forgive me if I am asking a bad question. When I was doing research for input of space separated value I got this statement.
    I understand that below statement takes value as `1 2 3` and returns value`[1, 2, 3]`as a list.

Kindly correct me if I am wrong,

- Stream: is used on collection for iteration.
- bufferedReader.readLine(): it reads the line as string
- replaceAll: is replacing space with `,` later it gets parse into Integer and being collected into List

My doubt is when I am inputting `1 2 3` which is a string. So, is this stream first splitting the value with space then iterating on splitted value? or is it 1st parsing the value later storing the value in list later splitting value with space and removing space and replacing with `,`. I am very curious, how exactly below statement is working.

```
List<Integer> a = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(toList());


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlXxd.jpg
```

Comment: `String[] s = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s$", "").split(" ");` Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Naman atually I want to understand how given statement is working.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: `.replaceAll("\\s$", "")` is obsolete, the subsequent `.split(" ")` will skip empty strings at the end anyway.

Comment: The whole thing would be far better as `bufferedReader.lines().flatMap(String::split).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(toList())`. E&OE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `bufferedReader.readLine()` reads one line, as a `String`. The string isn't assigned to any variable.
- `replaceAll("\\s$", "")` is anchored at the end of the line and removes the last whitespace. Using `String#trim` would have been better.
- `split(" ")` splits the string into a `String[]`, breaking it apart at whitespaces
- `Stream.of(String[])` takes the `String[]` we now have and returns a `Stream<String>`
- `Stream<String>.map(Function<String, Integer>)` converts the `Stream<String>` into a `Stream<Integer>` by applying the mapping function (`Integer::parseInt`) to each element of the stream
- `Stream<Integer>#collect(toList())` takes a `String<Integer>` and collects it into a `List<Integer>`
- `List<Integer> a = ...` assigns the result of the aforementioned steps to the variable `a`

And then you are done.

The comma you are seeing when using `System.out.println(a)` are produced by calling `List#toString()` (actually, [`AbstractCollection#toString`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l464), which is inherited by most List implementations via `Abstractlist`), which produces a comma-separated list of values, enclosed in square brackets. This is a string representation for easier readability by us humans and has nothing to do with how the list is stored internally. In an `ArrayList` for example, the internal storage would be `Integer[]`, other list implementations use other data structures.
Some debugger similarly show the contents of lists and arrays as such comma-separated lists - this is again purely for easier readability.

Comment: I am attaching a screenshot, kindly see it is also adding a comma with space in the numbers. I don't now how exactly it is working. I can copy and paste the code it will be working but I want to understand it how is it working.

Comment: @Brain I have just added another paragraph explaining why you see a comma-separated list of values when printing.

Comment: `trim()` is not identical, as it removes more than one whitespace character if present and also removes at the beginning *and* the end. On the other hand, the `split(" ")` will ignore empty strings at the end anyway, so if the whitespace in question is a space character, the `replaceAll` is entirely obsolete. If the whitespace in question is not a space character, it still is possible to let `split` handle it, e.g. via `.split(" |\\s$")`. In either case, there is no need for two string operations…

Comment: @Holger Yes, trim does also remove from the beginning, which is probably better. OP is very vague on the requirements, but in every use-case I can imagine I'd use `trim`. I'd also not split on `" "`, but on `"\\s+"` to avoid empty entries when there are multiple whitespace between two entries. Its likely the reader reads from stdin, although we don't know that for sure, so imho trying to clean up the input a bit would be prudent.

Comment: @Holger Also, the author obviously tried to remove all trailing whitespace and failed (removing just one), just illustrating that relying on methods like `trim` is less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the

`.replaceAll("\\s$", "")`

replaces a space with a comma, but that is not what it does. It replaces all occurences of a whitespace at the end of a string with no nothing. (`\s` is any whitespace and `$` is for end of string).

After this the string is split into an array, separator being a space: " ". Then all cells are parsed into integers and collected as a list.

The replace seems a bit weird, but I cannot say if is necessary or not without knowing the context. It looks like that [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) would fit better.

Comment: “all occurences of a whitespace at the end” is a contradiction in itself. There can be only one whitespace character at the end.